# Opening a connection to SQL Server 2014 database with ADO in VB

Tags: sql-server, database, vsto, ado

I'm trying to connect to my database in SQL Server 2014 with ADO in Visual Basic. I want to take my table called `payroll` and store the column `employee` into a `RecordSet`. My database is called `Employee`, my table is called `Payroll` and the column I want to retrieve from the table `Payroll` is called `Employee`. I am getting an error on my `cnn.open` line:

> An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in WordInvoice.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.

Code:

```
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

Public Class ThisDocument
    Private Sub ThisDocument_Startup() Handles Me.Startup
        Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
        Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
        cnn.Open("Provider=SQLOLEDB;" &
                 "Data Source={DANNY};" &
                 "Initial Catalog={Employee};" &
                 "Integrated Security={SSPI};")
        rst.Open("SELECT Employee FROM Payroll;", cnn, ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenStatic)
        rst.MoveFirst()

    End Sub

    Private Sub ThisDocument_Shutdown() Handles Me.Shutdown

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: What is the full, exact error message that you are getting?

Comment: @TabAlleman Appended error message to original question.